# Magento login form caches

Tags: magento

in my magento store sometimes in login form I see username and password of other users and I can login to their account.
This problem is not permanent and rarely it happens and I do not know when it happens.
My guess is the problem of cache or cookie.
I disabled cache for login form but this problem happened again.
Please help me how can I fix this problem?

Comment: on which magento version you are working..

Comment: my magento version is 1.9.1.0 .

Comment: are you using cache on your server can you share your website link?

Comment: Yes I use litespeed cache on my website but I disabled cache for login form.